# How does Mac OSX prioritize network interfaces when routing?

Tags: macos, networking, netstat, ifconfig

To give a concrete example, how does OSX choose which of these default entries from `netstat -nr` to route to?

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
0/1                10.10.99.100       UGSc            0        0    ppp0
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc            5        0     en0
default            192.168.1.1        UGScI           1        0     en1
default            192.0.2.1          UGScI         157        2    ppp0
```

From what I have been able to tell OSX uses metrics on its interfaces rather than on its routing table entries. But by default all of those interface metrics are 0 so how does it choose? Last created interface?

I've seen some folks suggest its the order in the Network preferences, but in my case the ppp0 interface (from SonicWall NetExtender) isn't listed there.

There is some discussion in this [thread](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2011/Nov/msg00004.html), but no answer that I see.

Comment: Have you find out how to set route metric?

Comment: @Samir Sogay answers it, but here's a howto:  https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-order-network-ports-mac-mchlp2711/mac

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most systems follows these rules when choosing which route to use:

- Find the most *specific* ones (i.e. the ones with the longest matching prefix).
- Choose the one with the highest *priority*.

On Linux (and, I think, on Windows) priority is determined by *metric*, but it is not the case on macOS as you correctly pointed out. Instead of assigning metrics to individual routes, macOS assigns [priorities to interfaces](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25445). You can use `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder` to view this order and `networksetup -ordernetworkservices` to change it.

Now, this route from your output makes me think that in your case specificity also plays its role:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
0/1                10.10.99.100       UGSc            0        0    ppp0
```

This route covers the bottom half of the address space and therefore I would expect to also find:

```
128.0/1            10.10.99.100       UGSc            0        0    ppp0
```

in your routing table. This is a standard trick VPN software uses to prioritise its routes over `default`: it adds two routes which together cover all IP addresses, but each of them is more specific than default, so they win.

Comment: On Linux, priority is only determined by metric for single routing table cases, however higher priority rules can override metric of routes from another tables with lower prio rule entry in multiple routing table cases. Also with dynamic routing, one has to consider the lowest administrative distance.

Comment: Thanks you so much for: "This is a standard trick VPN software uses to prioritise its routes over default". This finally helped me understand WTF was going on in my case.

Answer (score 18):

Any routing table which has multiple default routes with equal metrics does load balancing. The case with a mac though is that it will select the first interface which is in the interface list. If you want to see and change the list, go to "open network preferences", here you will see a list of network interfaces like ethernet, airport, ppp through mobile or 3g, etc. Below the list, you will see an asterisk shaped option with a down arrow. Click this and set the "set service order". Here you can change preference of your particular interface.

http://www.sustworks.com/site/prod_ipnrx_help/html/AlternateRouteHelp.html

Comment: Is there any source you can reference that confirms this? If you can reference a site that'll make your answer more worthwhile and people will vote it up.

Comment: "Set service order" can be confirmed here: [OS X Mountain Lion: Change the priority of your network connections](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10971)

Comment: That link above is broken, so here's a new one :) https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-order-network-ports-mac-mchlp2711/mac

Comment: I came here looking for an answer and the recommended "solution" is not a solution in my case. Service order has no effect on which interface is used first.