# Access the internet directly while connected to VPN

Tags: vpn, split-tunnel

I'm using Pulse Secure on a Mac OS. When I connect to my company VPN I can access their servers but can't access any external website.

Is it possible to tinker with the VPN client to have access to both internet and local servers?

I've been searching around for info on VPN split tunneling and modifying the routing tables but now I feel stuck. Is there a solution that can be applied on the client side regardless of the VPN client?

Comment: Virtual machines. Connect VPN on one of the VMs and do your work-work there, then the rest of the OS would be free to connect to the internet however it sees fit. However, if this is a work computer the correct answer would be: You shouldn't be asking us, you should be asking your work IT people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit involved but the first thing you'll want to do is be sure that this is not against the rules for whatever VPN host you're connecting to.  If it's your employer it's likely that they have a policy against this and I wouldn't want to give you information that might get you in hot water.

With that said, the first step is to get a picture of your routing table before and after connection to the VPN.

You can do that using the command: `netstat -rn`

You can use those 2 tables to compare the routing table with and without VPN.  What's probably happening is that a **default** route is being created that routes all of your traffic to the next hop on the other side of the VPN tunnel.  You can then delete or adjust that route and or the metrics to route traffic in the desired flow.

There's some good information on OSX routing [here](https://superuser.com/questions/472454/how-does-mac-osx-prioritize-network-interfaces-when-routing) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1015878/how-to-set-route-specific-interface-metrics-under-mac-os-x)

I would give more info but I'm @ work right now and cannot type the required novel to give a detailed how-to.  If this isn't enough to get you started pm me and I will respond accordingly (updating answer if need be).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you already mention the only solution you get, that modify the routing table by yourself. 
VPN server configuration says to your client to create a default route where all traffic have to pass. If you have the admins right on that computer (do not know apple very well but I suppose there have sudo). Also split tunneling (have to be confirmed) is not configurable by your side (without editing the route).

Anyway I'm not sure if you edit the route by your self this will gonna really work, should try it.